# Regex Detect Double Space

Tags: regex, double, spaces

I am trying to get a regex that will detect if there is a double space in a string. But if it does detect a double space it will return as false. So essentially anything else in the string is valid except for two spaces side by side. In the examples below the underscores (_) are spaces.

'Hello_World' ==> Valid

'Hello__World' ==> Invalid

'Hello___World' ==> Invalid

'1_2_3_4_5' ===> Valid

'1_2_3__4_5' ==> Invalid

This is my current regex

`/^([^/s/s]*)$/`

Comment: Where's your regex?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, `/^([^/s/s]*)$/` is not a valid regex. At least it is rather meaningless, it matches a string that contains of 0+ chars other than `/` and `s`. What did you mean to say with that pattern?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I am trying to detect if two of the same characters side by side are present in the string. I know `/^([^a]*)$/` will detect if the letter "a" is present but I want to detect if two spaces are present in the string.

Comment: Then just use `if (!/\s{2}/.test(s)) { /*CORRECT*/ }`. Or something like `if (s.Contains("  ")) { /*bad*/ }` (two spaces inside contains)

Comment: Ok, just use `^\S+(?:\s\S+)*$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of focusing on what 2 spaces *isn't*, use a negative look ahead for what it *is*:

```
^(?!.*  ).+
```

Or if the 1st and last must be non-spaces (not stated):

```
^\S((?!.*  ).*\S)?$
```

Which also allows exactly 1 non-space as the entire input.

---

The primary thing that makes this work is this expression `^(?!.*  )`, which a *negative* look-ahead `(?!.*  )` *anchored* to start of input by `^`. It asserts, without consuming input, that the text that follows the current point does *not* match the given expression, in this case `".*  "` (quotes added for clarity), which is "anything then two spaces". In other words "two spaces do not appear at any point after here".

The second option could have been written `^\S(?!.*  ).*\S$` - that same as the first but with `\S` at either end, but that would require *different* characters at each end because `\S` consumes input, so it wouldn't match a single letter eg `"X"`. My making all characters other than the first *optional*, it allows the single character to pass (as per your requirements), while retaining the prevention of two spaces.

Comment: They both seem to work perfectly. How does it work? Can you please break the regex down and explain the sections.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I am after.

Comment: @Peter - Here's a couple of web app tools I use that should help visualize and understand what the regex patterns do exactly, and help with experimenting to find additional patterns:

https://regex101.com/
https://www.debuggex.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like that

```
^(\S\s{0,1})*\S$
```